# Firefox triple click selection returns incorrect start and end offsets

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, selection

I have this piece of code which is supposed to return the start and end offsets of the user selection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function getSelRange() {
      var selObj = window.getSelection();
      var range  = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
      alert(range.startOffset+"-"+range.endOffset);
    }

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="getSelRange()">Get the selected text!</button>
    <p>Select some text!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I select some text from the `p` by dragging, it alerts the numbers correctly. However, when I select the entire text in the `p` by triple clicking on it, it alerts **0-1**. Looks like in Firefox only, triple click doesn't return the selection range correctly.

How do I get the correct start and end points on triple click as well?

Answer (score 4):

Firefox is returning the correct range. The problem is that your assumption that a range must have its start and end boundaries relative to a text node is incorrect.

What is happening is that Firefox is reporting the range as starting before the zeroth child node of the `<p>` element and ending after the first child of the `<p>` element. This is perfectly valid.

You could do something like the following to adjust such a range to make its boundaries lie inside the text node within the `<p>` element:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DbmjH/2/

Code:

```
function adjustRange(range) {
    range = range.cloneRange();
    if (range.startContainer.nodeType != 3) {
        var nodeAfterStart = range.startContainer.childNodes[range.startOffset];
        if (nodeAfterStart && nodeAfterStart.nodeType == 3) {
            range.setStart(nodeAfterStart, 0);
        }
    }
    if (range.endContainer.nodeType != 3 && range.endOffset >= 1) {
        var nodeBeforeEnd = range.endContainer.childNodes[range.endOffset - 1];
        if (nodeBeforeEnd && nodeBeforeEnd.nodeType == 3) {
            range.setEnd(nodeBeforeEnd, nodeBeforeEnd.data.length);
        }
    }
    return range;
}
```

Comment: Tim this is the same output i am getting in my answer

Comment: @Zword: Possibly so, for some examples. In general, they're not the same at all. I don't really understand what your answer is trying to do.

Comment: Ha ha, I can always expect an answer from Tim when the question concerns selection range. :)

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Not as reliably as a few years ago

Comment: @TimDown thanks for this answer. And for rangy. But, I'm getting these results even when I'm using rangy; I'd expect rangy to abstract away this cross-browser differences for me. Is that a bug in rangy?

Comment: @Marc: Not a bug as such. Rangy abstracts API differences (principally IE <= 8) and works around known bugs in implementations. It doesn't try to hide these differences because the browser's idea of what is selected has to be definitive, and what the browser thinks is selected also affects behaviour. Normalizing selection boundaries is impractical because it's impossible to know what normalization is appropriate and desirable in every situation.

Answer (score 1):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3z9/8/) ( <kbd>Updated</kbd> )

I have made it in a way that it will work on triple click when paragraph contains multiple lines.

```
<script>
    function getSelRange() {
        var selObj = window.getSelection();
        var range = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
        var r = document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML.split('<br>');

        if (r[(range.endOffset-1)/2] == selObj) {
            alert(0+"-"+r[(range.endOffset-1)/2].length);
        } else if (range.startOffset >= range.endOffset) {
            alert(range.startOffset + "-" + r[(range.endOffset-1)/2].length);
        } else {
            alert(range.startOffset + "-" + range.endOffset);
        }  
    }
</script>
```

---

### [New Added Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3z9/15/)

```
<script>
function getSelRange() {
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    var range  = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    var r=document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML.split('<br>');
    var selLines = selObj.toString().split('\n');

    var Str = document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML;
    Str=Str.replace(/<br>/g,"xzznlzzx");
    var pr=selObj.toString().replace(/\r?\n/g,"xzznlzzx");
    var rStr=Str.substring(0,Str.indexOf(pr));

    var rSplit=rStr.split('xzznlzzx');
    var prSplit=pr.split('xzznlzzx');

    var countStart=0;
    var countEnd=0;
    var i=0;
    for(;i<(rSplit.length-1);i++)
    {
        countStart=countStart+r[i].length;
    }
    for(j=0;j<(prSplit.length-1);i++,j++)
    {
        countEnd=countEnd+r[i].length;
    }

    countEnd=countEnd+countStart;
    if(r[(range.endOffset-1)/2]==selObj)
    {
    alert((0+countStart)+"-"+(r[(range.endOffset-1)/2].length+countEnd));
    }
    else{
        if(r[i].length<selObj.toString().length)
        {
        var indx = selObj.toString().indexOf(r[i]);
        }
        else{
        var indx = r[i].indexOf(selObj.toString());
        var vals=selObj.toString().length;
        var res = r[i].substring(indx+vals,indx+vals+1);
        if(res==""){indx=1}
        else{indx=-1}
        }
        if(indx!=-1)
        {
        alert((range.startOffset+countStart)+"-"+(r[i].length+countEnd));
        }
        else{
        alert((range.startOffset+countStart)+"-"+(range.endOffset+countEnd));
        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

***Note : for the above fiddles to work the string within `<p>` tag must be in a single line otherwise it will add the extra spaces between words to the range.***

Comment: It almost works, but if I change the inner HTML of the `p` to `Check this out<br>Foo` to make it two lines, then if I choose either line by triple click, it still returns `0-1`..

Comment: Thanks. But now another problem, if the selection is made through dragging and spanning multiple lines, say from the middle of the second line to the middle of the third line, the start and end both are counted individually with respect to the corresponding lines.

Comment: Can you tell me what output you want on selecting multiple lines?

Comment: I want the start and end as if the entire text within the `p` is in one go, there is no `<br>`.

Comment: @Cupidvogel I have added a new fiddle.The code is a bit long because it requires many checks to make it work.Hope this helps you