# Why are some of the span attributes lost when deleting a paragraph?

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have a simple HTML as mentioned below. When the first paragraph is deleted(triple click and hit delete). The "span2" flows into "FirstPara" and I see that the attributes like "id" and "class" are not retained. Why is it so? Is there a way to stop this from happening?

```html
<div id="MainDiv" contenteditable="true" style="height: 200pt; width: 300pt;">
    <p id="FirstPara">
        <span id="span1" class="Test1" style="font-weight: bold;">FirstParagraph</span>
    </p>
    <p id="SecondPara">
        <span id="span2" class="Test2" style="font-style: italic;">SecondParagraph</span>
    </p>
    <p id="ThirdPara">
        <span id="span3" class="Test3" style="text-decoration-line: underline;">ThirdParagraph</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser and OS? Does it happen on other browsers/OS'es?

Comment: I am seeing this behavior in Chrome 42 on Windows 8

Comment: I observed this on Chrome 42, Chrome Canary 44, Safari 8 on Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

I think is becose, if you triple click, you select white space whot create "SecondPara" and delete them. Remains beginning of the first and second end = for browser first full.

The solution I see in using Span place paragraph and change css for this span.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the selection range starts at the beginning of the *textNode* and ends at the beginning of *#SecondPara*:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
range.startContainer; // TextNode: "FirstParagraph"
range.startOffset; // 0;
range.endContainer; // <p id="SecondPara">...</p>
range.endOffset; // 0
```

The only way to work around this is to manually change the selection to only include *#FirstPara*, but this can get a bit tricky making it work under all conditions (you have to think about reverse selections, browser compatibility, etc.) See this similar question for a starting place: [Firefox triple click selection returns incorrect start and end offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229067/firefox-triple-click-selection-returns-incorrect-start-and-end-offsets)

Comment: Thanks JosiahDaniels you are right, if this is the case then should it matter if SecondPara has multiple spans? Because what I see is replacing the tag <p id="SecondPara">...</p> with the following is not behaving the same. It is in fact retaining the attributes.                                                       <p id="SecondPara">
   <span id="span2" class="Test2" style="font-style: italic;">SecondParagraph</span>
   <span id="span4" class="Test2" style="font-weight: bold;">DummySpan</span>
  </p>

Comment: I could certainly see that adding more spans to SecondPara could change things. I'm not very confident on the browser's element merging/deleting algorithms, but the fact that SecondPara contains two spans could certainly make a difference.