# double-click highlight text retrieves next LI element when doing getSelection()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I'm using Summernote but I also noticed this happens even using plane javascript that whenever you double-click on a bulleted list item to highlight it, and trying to retrieve that LI element you selected, returns the next item on the list instead of the one you just highlighted.

Here's an example:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
 this.getHighlightedElement();
}.bind(this));

function getHighlightedElement() {
  var selectedNode = window.getSelection().focusNode;
  $('.result').empty();
  $('.result').append($(selectedNode).clone());
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Double-click on the first LI item to highlight it:

<ul>
  <li>This is text #1</li>
  <li>This is text #2</li>
</ul>

<div class="container"> Highlighted element:
  <span class="result"></span>
</div>

<button id="btn">GET SELECTION</button>
```

Try the following:

**1) Double click on first item and click the button to see selection:**

The highlighted text based on the browser it says it's the second item. That's completely wrong.

**2) Double click to select the second item:**

It shows a totally different element, in this case is the text below.

**3) Click+Swipe to highlight text normally:**

Expect correct and normal behavior.

Why is this happening? Any clues? how can I avoid it?

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me, maybe im doing something wrong, just giving you some feedback.

Comment: Did you try what i wrote there? double-click to select the whole first item on the list, then click the button.. what does it show in the result??? 1st or 2nd list item? Thanks for replying. I'm using Chrome latest version in MacOS, btw.

Comment: Ah! It seems to be different on Windows, i had to triple click, I got the same result as you, Chrome Lastest Version Windows 10

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229067/firefox-triple-click-selection-returns-incorrect-start-and-end-offsets

Comment: Just a hunch, but could it be that you're binding to the `click` event, not the `dblclick` event?

Comment: @monners no, i just have it bound like that so i can give you an example, doesn't matter how you do it, it will return that, i'm using summernote RTE and when i debug their code and placed a breakpoint, i was able to see that i was returning the next item...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
$(window.getSelection().anchorNode)
```

In my case, I also had to search for the "li" elements above using jQuery parents() function.

```
$(window.getSelection().anchorNode).parents('li')
```