# Triple click text in Chrome contains the following node in range

Tags: javascript, range, selection

Im seeing different range behaviour when I drag select a node vs. when I triple click select a node.

When I drag select, both the start and end containers contain the text that I highlighted. This is the desired outcome.

When I triple click a node in Chrome, Im seeing the end container is the following node, not the text node that I see highlighted.

What I would expect is the range to contain only the text node that is selected on the triple click.

Here is a reproducible example

js

```
document.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    var r = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var start = r.startContainer.nodeType===3?r.startContainer:r.startContainer.childNodes[r.startOffset];
  var end = r.endContainer.nodeType===3?r.endContainer:r.endContainer.childNodes[r.endOffset];
  console.log(e.detail, start, end);
})
```

html

```
<p>
Triple click the h2 and you'll see the following p tag content in the console. 
</p>
<p>
Drag select the h2 tag, and the p tag content will not be present in the console.
</p>

<div>

  <h2>I'm a h2</h2> 
  <p>Why do you see me in the console?</p>
  
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kz0u85q6/

Ive tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21234837/5779280), but it doesnt seem to be the same.

Edit: This is what the range looks like when I triple click the H2 element text

[image]

Comment: According to MDN, [`.endOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endOffset) is "the number of child nodes between the start of the `endContainer` and the boundary point of the Range". So you should probably be using `.childNodes[r.endOffset-1]` to get the last element in the range.

Comment: However the endoffset in this case is 0. Meaning that the childNodes[-1] returns undefined which Im not sure what to make of.

Comment: Is it? When I tried your jsfiddle example, `r.endOffset` was `1` and `.endContainer.childNodes.length` was `1`, so the returned value was `undefined`.

Comment: Well thats really weird then... If I could attach an image I would, but I definetly have `r.endOffset` as 0. Edit: Added an image of the range from the triple click.

Comment: Is it just Chrome that does that? I'm in Firefox.

Comment: Just confirmed that in firefox, the endOffset is set to 1.

Comment: My interpretation is that the Range is `[begin,end)`, as in the beginning marker is part of the selection but the end marker is not. How that's represented in Chrome vs Firefox is different, but the results appear to be effectively the same. Though Chrome's variation makes finding the last included element difficult in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the *triple click* action in Chrome is selecting whole line, including *end-of-line* characters. That is why the *endContainer* is pushed down to the next node. The easiest solution I see is to detect that the event is for a *triple click* and then just ignore provided *endContainer*. In the example below you get the same result with *triple click* and with *click and drag*:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const clicks = e.detail;
  const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  const start = range.startContainer;
  const end = clicks === 3 ? start : range.endContainer;

  console.log(clicks, start, end);
});
```

```html
<p>
  Triple click the h2 and you'll see the following p tag content in the console.
</p>
<p>
  Drag select the h2 tag, and the p tag content will not be present in the console.
</p>

<div>

  <h2>I'm a h2</h2>
  <p>Why do you see me in the console?</p>

</div>
```